# Like pressing "q", but from the other window

Tags: window, keystrokes

I run a command that takes over another window, and maybe resizes it a little, but doesn't focus it. Let's say `C-h e` or `C-x C-b`.

I can go to that window and press `q` there, and everything goes back to the previous state (the window resizes back, its previous content is restored, focus is back to the original window).

I want to be get the same effect without having to go to that window. Instead of `C-h e C-x o q` I want to be able to do `C-h e <some keystroke that will close the most recently opened closeable-by-pressing-q window>`.

---

(Months later) I found a simpler and more straightforward way... sometimes the simpler things elude us... (I'm leaving the "solved" mark where it is anyway):

```lisp
(defun quit-other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (other-window 1)
  (quit-window))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c q") #'quit-other-window)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You can use the `windmove-delete-up`, `-down`, `-left` and `-right` functions. I use them with these bindings:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c W") #'windmove-delete-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c S") #'windmove-delete-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c A") #'windmove-delete-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c D") #'windmove-delete-right)
```

Say I type `C-h e` and it opens the *Messages* buffer in a window below the current one, which remains selected, then I can type `C-c S` to delete the *Messages* buffer's window.

Otherwise you can enable `winner-mode` and use `winner-undo`, which will undo the latest change to the arrangement of the windows. `winner-mode` binds some keys by default when it is loaded, so if you want to have `winner-undo` always available but use your own key bindings, you could add this to your init file

```lisp
(setq winner-dont-bind-my-keys t)
(winner-mode)
```

and then, for example

```lisp
(define-key winner-mode-map (kbd "C-c q") #'winner-undo)
(define-key winner-mode-map (kbd "C-c e") #'winner-redo)
```

Comment: Thanks, Arch. The first one doesn't work when the frame is already split and the function takes over an existing window. The `windmove-delete-*` functions just delete it, so they don't restore the original layout. `winner-undo` works like a charm, though.